# Cannot install phpmyadmin, getting conflict errors

Tags: centos, yum, phpmyadmin

I want to install `phpmyadmin` but I get this error.

```
php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
php70w-common conflicts with php56w-common-5.6.31-2.w6.x86_64
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php70w-common-7.0.24-1.w6.x86_64
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php56w-common-5.6.31-2.w6.x86_64
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: Add the command you are using to install phpmyadmin.

Comment: please add the output of `yum repolist`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have 2 repos enabled (base/epel and Remi maybe?)
make sure to disable one of them.